# date error handling in Access SQL

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have a table `x` with the following values of type Text:

```
+-----------+
| dateValue |
+-----------+
| 12/9/1906 |
| 7/49/54   |
| 27945     |
+-----------+
```

I want to query this table and return the date equivalent of each string, or the original string and an error indicator if the string cannot be parsed to a date.

I tried this:

```
select iif(isError(cdate(dateValue)),dateValue&" isError",cdate(dateValue))
as parseDate from x
```

which should return `7/49/54 isError` for the invalid string, but that query instead returns:

```
+-----------+
| parseDate |
+-----------+
| 12/9/1906 |
| #Error    |
| 7/4/1976  |
+-----------+
```

Is there any way to handle the invalid date string to return the desired result?

EDIT: added the `cdate()` parse in the query.

Answer (score 1):

I would use IsDate() function instead of IsError() because CDate() would throw an #Error if argument is not a valid date expression.  Try this one:

```
select iif(IsDate(dateValue), cdate(dateValue), dateValue & " isError")
as parseDate from x
```

Comment: This doesn't parse the `27945` value correctly; I had to use this for the conditional check instead: `isdate(dateValue) or isnumeric(dateValue)`

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to mix types.  You have a string in one row and a date in another.  That isn't possible.  You could do:

```
select iif(isError(cdate(dateValue)),dateValue&" isError", dateValue) as parseDate
from x
```